# Does GitHub Support svn:needs-lock?

Tags: svn, github

Our FIRST robotics team is working with binary CAD/CAM files and has been making a mess with unmergeable files in git and GitHub. GitHub [supports SVN](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/), and SVN [allows binary files to be locked](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html), but when I use the command `svn propset svn:needs-lock true ControlsBox.iam` followed by `svn ci .`, I get the following error:

```
svn: E175008: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175008: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
svn: E160024: Invalid PROPPATCH property
```

Is this an indirect indication that GitHub doesn't support the `svn:needs-lock` property or that I'm doing something wrong? Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, Git does not support file locking. But I know of at least two distributed systems that do: [Veracity](https://sourcegear.com/veracity/), and [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com) (if you install the [lock extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LockExtension)). I'm not sure whether Veracity is still under active development, and it doesn't look there is a good hosting site for it anymore. Mercurial, on the other hand, is very active, has a large number of users, and support on many hosting sites including BitBucket if you want a central server without the hassle of managing it yourself. Like Git, both of these systems also support starting up lightweight servers to allow users to push/pull between each other instead of using a central server, but there does need to be some sort of central location to store locks since the whole point of this exercise is to use those. Sadly the major hosting providers do not support the lock extension for Mercurial, that I know of.

Of course, you could also use SVN. <s>Google Code and</s> Sourceforge and other places offer free SVN hosting, though none as nice as GitHub or even BitBucket (that I know of). A self-hosted SVN server takes a lot more setup than the distributed tools, but there are simple tools to help with that as well like [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/).

Answer (score 3):

The Subversion [locking feature that you mention](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html) is implemented on the *server*:

> Firstly you need to ensure that your Subversion server is upgraded to at least version 1.2. Earlier versions do not support locking at all.

GitHub [supports Subversion *clients*](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/):

> GitHub repositories can be accessed from both Git and Subversion (SVN) clients.

No mention is made of Subversion on the server. Quite the opposite, in fact:

> GitHub supports Subversion clients via the HTTPS protocol. We use a Subversion bridge to communicate svn commands to GitHub.

No matter how you access a GitHub repository, it remains a Git repository on the server. Since Git doesn't support file locking, GitHub doesn't support file locking.

This conclusion is supported by the list of Subversion features that GitHub supports, which makes no mention of locking (from the same article):

- Checkout
- Creating branches
- Making commits to Subversion

  Note that this really means committing to GitHub using the `svn` command:

  > After you've added some features and fixed some bugs, you'll want to commit those changes to GitHub. This works just like the Subversion you're used to. Edit your files, and use `svn commit` to record your changes
- Switching between branches